# FragmentTransaction's setCustomAnimation() giving error

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my code, on line `transaction.setCustomAnimations()`, the IDE is showing:

```
Expected Resource of Type Animator
```

Here is my code:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;

private void loadPasswordFragment() {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment mFragment = new ForgotWithPasswordFrag();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations( R.anim.fade_out, R.anim.fade_in);
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, mFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by using `android.R.animator.fade_in` instead of `R.anim.fade_in`.